# Place a control inside 3D object wpf

Tags: wpf, 3d, expression-blend, viewport

There are several tutorials that show you how to create 3d objects such as this[`Introduction to WPF 3D`](http://www.wpftutorial.net/IntroductionTo3D.html). Moreover I could create the 3d objects in other applications and then import them with expression blend.

If my 3d object is a cube for example how could I place a user control in one of the faces of the cube? When I imported my 3d object to my application expression blend created a viewport control. I was wondering if it is possible to place a control inside that object such as a button. I have tried placing the button inside that viewport and it does not work. Is it possible to place a user control inside a 3d object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Viewport2dVisual3d` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d.aspx).
This class allows live interactive 2D content to be directly mapped to a 3D surface.

You should break the mesh up to have a separate mesh for each face then use a `Viewport2dVisual3d` for each face and add your control to that face.